# How the NTILE (MS SQL) function ranks equal values

Tags: sql-server, sorting, quantile

I did the distribution of ratings by parameters: RECENCY aka R, MONETARY aka M, FREQUENCY aka F, using NTILE function. All parameters varies from 1 to positive infinity.
My script:

```
SELECT 
r.phone,
r.R,
r.F,
r.M,
NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY R desc) as R_S,
NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY F asc) as F_S,
NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY M asc) as M_S
FROM rfm_raw r
```

but I have a lot of equal parameters. For example FREQUENCY = 1. I want to know how NTILE function sorting rows with the same FREQUENCY?

This is image of F_SCORE variation calculated by NTILE function with the same FREQUENCY. F_SCORE changed at different periods because of different data provided to script, but with the smalest FREQUENCY the same ID had bigger F_SCORE at 2022-05-01 then at 2022-04-01.

[image: Result example]

Comment: Like with anything involving `ORDER BY`, if the clause does not provide a unique (set of) value(s) then the order is arbitrary when there is a tie.

Comment: If you don't provide sufficient expressions to *deterministically* determine the order, the server is free to produce any result consistent with the non-deterministic requirements you've asked for. If you want certainty, provide it by providing more ordering constraints.